# To run an AHK script after detecting USB External EHDD

Tags: hard-drive, script, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script in AHK(Auto Hot Key) to detect if there is any External HDD is connected and then run the next command in the script. Suppose below is the script.

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want A to C to be script to check if an External Drive is connected. If Yes the command will go to line D or else go to line E. I already checked for some scripts but no luck. tried the script in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298320/how-do-i-find-usb-connected-removable-hard-drives-in-autohotkey) as reference but not sure how to modify based on my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the label of your external HDD(s) you could use this:

```
; get a list of all the hard drives. Hard drives are considered as FIXED by AHK
DriveGet, drives, list, FIXED
Loop, Parse, drives  ; loop through each drive letter
{
  DriveGet, DriveLabel, Label, %A_LoopField%:  ; get the drive label

  ; IF DriveLabel not contains External HDD1 label,External HDD2 label
  IF (DriveLabel != "External HDD label")  ; If you want to use only one External HDD
    Continue

  ExternalDriveLetter := A_LoopField  ; get the drive letter of the last found

   ;    or 
  ; get the drive letter of the first found
   ; ExternalDriveLetter = %A_LoopField%
     ; Break

}
IfExist, %ExternalDriveLetter%:
    Run %ExternalDriveLetter%:  ; go to line D
else
    MsgBox, No External HDD is connected        ; go to line E
```

Comment: Hi @user3419297 Thanks for the above coding it works fine but. I want the script to keep running in background and exit when i exit from Icon tray. Besides I am going to use un-formatted HDD and I want the script to detect the HDD whenever I connect and if the HDD is detected I want to perform the next line in the script.

Comment: The solution is much simpler if you get the message "Disk in Drive ... is not formatted. Would you like to format it now?" whenever you connect the HDD. All you need in this case is a timer to detect the message window.

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop
{
    WinWaitActive, DiskInDrive   ; put the title in here for the dialog box to wait for indefinitely -- will need to exit from tray

    ; put code here to execute any time the window is active
    ; after code is done, program will loop and wait again

}
```

If the dialog box doesn't become active by default you can also use WinWait and WinActivate prior to the WinWaitActive statement above.